# get selected row id jquery datatable row selection

Tags: javascript, css, json, model-view-controller, datatables

i cannot get selected row id. I'm using datatable row selection.  I'm getting [],[""] in console log.  I have looked for other questions on SO  and tried but no help

My javascript code is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedids = [];

    var otable = $('#Table1').DataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
            if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selectedids) !== -1) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
    $('#Table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = $.inArray(id, selectedids);

        var ids = $.map(otable.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
            return item[0]
        });

        console.log(ids)

        if (index === -1) {
            selectedids.push(id);
            console.log(selectedids);
        } else {
            selectedids.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

});
```

I'm filling up my datatable with json data from controller in mvc

```
    $('#ID').change(function () {
    $("#t1 tbody tr").remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: $("#ID").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                var rows = "<tr>"
               + "<td>" + item.id + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + item.yyy + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + item.aaa + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + item.eee + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + item.yyygg + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";
                $('#Table1 tbody').append(rows);
            });

        },
        error: function (ex) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            alert("Message: " + r.Message);

            alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
            alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: What does your JSON data look like?  You should be able to pull the Id directly from your data/row object

Comment: i'm returrning from controller like this return Json(lstTickets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spare yourself a lot of pain, if you used dataTables [**select extension**](http://cdn.datatables.net/#Select) :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   select: {
      style: 'multi'
   }
}) 

var selectedIds = [];

table.on('select.dt', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
   selectedIds.push(indexes[0]);
   console.log(selectedIds);
})

table.on('deselect.dt', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
   selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(indexes[0]), 1);
   console.log(selectedIds);
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0w1p7a3s/**

Comment: i added datatable.select.min.js and select.dataTables.min.css but it is not selecting row. any idea?

Comment: @coder771, the select script needs to be added _after_ the dataTables script. See "external resources" in the fiddle.

Comment: i'm using bundles     ....bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatableJquery").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                     "~/Scripts/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/dataTables.select.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datatable").Include(
                     "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css",
                     "~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css",
                     "~/Content/select.dataTables.min.css"));

Comment: @coder771, Sry - but it is impossible for me to debug your ASP bundles remotely :) It seems alright, try set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` and see what it looks like, and check the console for 404 errors..

Comment: there are no 404 errors.but as in fiddle each row is assigned odd even class, i dont have that assigned.

Comment: i assume it is data with which it is not working. the second bit where i appended rows with json.

Comment: hey @coder771 , select are using `this.id` too, the internal DOM `id` for the row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98250/discussion-between-coder771-and-davidkonrad).